# IDE for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide

What is the new best IDE for ruby on rails development? I have used Komodo Edit and now using Netbeans 6.9.1

Comment: Do you honestly think that there's an absolutely best IDE? If so, you're too naïve.

Answer (score 3):

"Best" is subjective.

I find IntelliJ to be the overall winner IDE-wise.

I use Sublime Text 2 for non-IDE Rails development. Co-workers tends towards Vim.

<sub>Only because they don't want to learn Emacs, the clearly-superior text edit. Aaaand begin.</sub>